# Link-list JAWS feature (insert + F7) on dialog windows shows all background links

Tags: javascript, angular, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I use `role="document"` and Angular `$modalInstance` to implement dialog window (look at the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H14EO.png)).

And when I'm trying to use "Link List" JAWS feature (<kbd>insert</kbd> + <kbd>f7</kbd>) that described [there](http://www.htctu.fhda.edu/trainings/manuals/tutorials/readweb/links.html), JAWS show list of all background links (*Sign Off*, *Projetcs*, .etc).

What I have to do to get links **only from dialog window** and ignore **all background links**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to disable all links outside from the dialog window.

One quick way could be to set the `aria-hidden` attribute on the main container when the modal is opened, assuming that your modal does not belong to this container.

```
<div aria-hidden="true">My background content here... </div>
<div>my modal here</div>
```

This won't stop the user from using the tab key, but this would answer the question of not listing the background links when the modal is opened

Comment: Great answer. I'll just add that Insert+F7 lists *all* links on the page, you can't restrict its action besides disabling the now-unnecessary links.